# WCF .svc file has return types, Client code sees all void

Tags: c#, wcf

The screenshots will really clarify a lot of things. Basically, I have this service and using the WCF Test Client I can get a string back. However, the Client Side reference that I have created using Visual Studio says that my method returns as void.

The ServerConnection object in my Test() method is referencing my service reference variable created by Visual Studio.

Root.svc.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Text;

namespace chatService_SignalRService.Services
{
    // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the class name "Root" in code, svc and config file together.
    // NOTE: In order to launch WCF Test Client for testing this service, please select Root.svc or Root.svc.cs at the Solution Explorer and start debugging.
    public class Root : IRoot
    {
        public String DoWork()
        {
            return "Hello Bailey!";
        }
    }
}
```

IRoot.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Text;

namespace chatService_SignalRService.Services
{
    // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the interface name "IRoot" in both code and config file together.
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IRoot
    {
        [OperationContract]
        String DoWork();
    }
}
```

I am using a Portable Class library. I select that class library, add service reference, point the address to my web server, and Name it ServerCT.

Then in my Profile.cs which is under the Portable Class Library, I create an object and method.

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Classes
{
    public class Profile : User
    {

        public static ServerCT.RootClient ServerConnection = new ServerCT.RootClient();


        public void Test()
        {
            ServerConnection.DoWorkAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

Screenshots:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Post your full code here instead of posting screenshots. Nobody wants to retype your code from your screenshot in order to give you an answer.

Comment: I will post the code, there are maybe 5 lines of code across a few different files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generated Async methods are always void, since they are asynchronous and return no result. Instead, you should use `Completed` event for handling the result:

```
ServerConnection.DoWorkCompleted += (sender, args) => 
{
    Console.WriteLine($"DoWork result: {args.Result}");
};
ServerConnection.DoWorkAsync(); // void, the result is provided through event handler
```

If you want to make a synchronous call and acquire the result synchronously, then you should call the synchronous method `DoWork` like this:

```
ServerConnection.DoWork(); // returns string
```

Note that synchronous operations are not generated for some types of projects or\and configurations. For example, for Silverlight applications.

Comment: Visual Studio doesn't give me the option to call DoWork(), only DoWorkAsync().

Comment: Probably, it is somehow related to the implementation or configuration. Could you show your service implementation?

Comment: I have a portable class library, that class library has a service reference. I create an object of that service reference and make the DoWorkAsync() call. No DoWork() method is specified on client side.

Comment: It looks like it does not support synchronous operations. You need to use the approach, described in the first part of my answer.

Comment: Thank you for the excellent answer. I have already tested a basic implementation of this approach. I like it because I can make the call in a similar method signature as the service is constructed. Then from there just have to create a default constructor of my object that makes that call to map the onCompleted Event to a method that runs the logic from that result.